# How do you create an xsd:int instance in suds?

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm using suds 0.4

I'm trying to create a node like this (from example SOAP request):

```
<id xsi:type="xs:int">123456</id>
```

It is a parameter of a SOAP call and merely passing an int generates this:

```
<int>123456</int>
```

which gives me

```
Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl
```

So what I need is a way of creating the right type. I've tried creating an instance of xsd:int which works but then there is no way I can see of setting the value.

Anyone got any ideas?

**EDIT**

Code:

```
findResult = self.client.service.find(self._getSession(), 'Candidate', 123456)
```

or

```
find = self.client.factory.create('find')
find.session = self._getSession()
find.entityName = 'Candidate'
find.id = 123456
findResult = self.client.service.find(find)
```

Same result both times. It seems that it passes the id as text field. I've checked the type and I am definitely using an int type.
In the WSDL schema the parameter type is:

```
<xs:complexType name="find">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="session" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="entityName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Id anyType the problem here?

Comment: Can you show the code where are you setting the id parameter for the SOAP call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had "similar" problem, where i needed a value to have an xsi:type="xsd:int" ( [Suds write request missing datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13593950/696768) ) and for some reason this was not added to the xml

I eventually stumbled across this [Adding xsi:type and envelope namespace when using SUDS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10916433/696768) and adapted the solution there for my usage, basically a Suds plugin "rewriting" my Value element to include the xsi:type="xsd:int" attribute.

It might be that you can use similar approach to set a type on your outgoing SOAP.

Also a suggestion, might be that you know it, to output the SOAP:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: This is in fact what I ended up doing but it seemed messy as at the least it processes all nodes each time.

Comment: Yes i agree it is messy. I am fairly sure there must be other ways to do it that is better, but eventually i gave up and went with the way that worked..